# Apache POI in Android - awt dependency

Tags: java, android, apache, awt, apache-poi

Im trying to insert image to xls file using Apache POI **in Android**.
Its rather simple ([example](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Images)) but its using **java.awt** package to work with images, and last method

```
drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);
```

crashes with

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.awt.Dimension
```

that is right, because it not exists in android. 
But how to solve this? Poi complied in jar, so i cant replace this with fake class, and i cant find any versions of lib for android.

Comment: It's part of the JDK, so you just need the tools.jar in your CLASSPATH.

Comment: @duffymo like this 
`<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/lib/tools.jar"/>`

doesnt help

Comment: Then you didn't do it right: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NoClassDefFoundError when inserting image in Android app using Apache poi & MS Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21953493/noclassdeffounderror-when-inserting-image-in-android-app-using-apache-poi-ms-e)