# NoClassDefFoundError when inserting image in Android app using Apache poi & MS Excel

Tags: android, excel, image, apache-poi

I want to insert a PNG image into my Excel sheet using Apache poi.

To do that I use this code:

```
//add picture data to this workbook.
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("/sdcard/MYAPPFOLDER/logo_app.png");
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
int pictureIdx = workbook.addPicture(bytes, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG);
is.close();

CreationHelper helper = workbook.getCreationHelper();

// Create the drawing patriarch.  This is the top level container for all shapes. 
Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

//add a picture shape
ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();
//set top-left corner of the picture,
//subsequent call of Picture#resize() will operate relative to it
anchor.setCol1(0);
anchor.setRow1(0);
Picture pict = drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);

//auto-size picture relative to its top-left corner
pict.resize();
```

But in first time I have one error which I have solved by adding this library `commons-codec-1.8.jar` and now I have this error:

```
02-21 10:10:51.466: E/AndroidRuntime(31691): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-21 10:10:51.466: E/AndroidRuntime(31691): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.awt.Dimension
02-21 10:10:51.466: E/AndroidRuntime(31691):    at org.apache.poi.ss.util.ImageUtils.getImageDimension(ImageUtils.java:52)
02-21 10:10:51.466: E/AndroidRuntime(31691):    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFPicture.getImageDimension(HSSFPicture.java:243)
02-21 10:10:51.466: E/AndroidRuntime(31691):    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFPicture.getPreferredSize(HSSFPicture.java:163)
```

Which points to this line:

```
pict.resize();
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: did you find a solution for this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use pure Java libraries that involve graphics routines (`java.awt`), because Android hasn't implemented them, as it uses it's own graphics library. Bottom line is, you can't use the library you want with Android, although I'm sure there's other ways to do the task you want to do.

Android uses a few base types, namely `View`s, `Canvas`, and `Drawable`s. Take a look at those, and see if they meet your needs.

Comment: I know those types and have already used them, but now I am using apache poi library which needs those class, it is not me who need them, you understand ?

Comment: oooh, I hope no, therefore, no way to insert image through apache poi in android

Comment: You can't use any standard Java graphics library in Android, nor anything that extends the graphics library. Android just hasn't implemented that side, as they use their own libraries.

Comment: Fully agree with @PearsonArtPhoto

Comment: then what is the workaround to insert an image inside excel sheet in android

Comment: Look around a bit for a dedicated Android library. https://github.com/dennis-sheil/android-spreadsheet looks like it might work, but there might be others.

Answer (score 1):

you **cannot use** `java.awt.*` package in Android, use the **[Android UI elements](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html)** instead. See [related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992754/ui-design-tips-and-tutorials-for-android)

Comment: I have import this but same problems

Comment: I think you misunderstood: You must not import this! The _usage_ of classes from this package is **not** supported in Android